# Jeffreys prior parameter transformation and posteriors

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian

Question:

Let $X \sim Bin(n, \pi)$ with $\pi \in (0,1)$ and known $n$. Derive the expression of Jeffreys prior for $\pi$ in the following parametrization:

(a) Original parametrization with parameter $\pi$.

(b) Parametrization with $\phi = logit(\pi)$ as a parameter

(c) Parametrization with $\eta = arcsin(\sqrt{\pi})$ as a parameter

(d) Compute the posteriors for $\pi, \phi$ and $\eta$ under each parametrization considered in parts (a), (b) and (c).

What I have done:

I have no problem calculating the prior for $\pi$, I get

$$f(\pi) \propto \sqrt{\pi^{-1}(1-\pi)^{-1}} \tag1\label1$$
So the posterior for $\pi$ is
$$f(\pi|x) \propto L(\pi)\cdot f(\pi) \propto \pi^x(1-\pi)^{n-x}\sqrt{\pi^{-1}(1-\pi)^{-1}} \tag2\label2$$
Where $L(\pi)$ is the likelihood function.

I know that Jeffreys prior is invariant during one-to-one reparametrization and so is the likelihood function. So for both b) and c) I would just replace $\pi$ with $\phi$ or $\eta$ in \eqref{1} and then later do the same for d) in \eqref{2}.

Is this correct? I guess whats confusing me here is that we are to find a parametrization for both $\phi$ and $\eta$ but in my solution above I just used the exact same argument for both making one of the questions redundant.

The only difference I can think about is that for $\eta$ one should probably make sure that this is a one-to-one transformation by noting that $\pi \in (0,1)$ fulfills the requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: Alright, my mistake. Fixed it.

Comment: downvote and close vote removed, added eqn no. ref

Comment: See the answer in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498538/jeffreys-prior-invariance-under-reparametrization for an important point

Comment: In (2), I would have written the posterior density as $\propto \pi^{x-\frac12}(1-\pi)^{n-x-\frac12}$ or said the posterior distribution was $\textrm{Beta}\left(x+\frac12,n-x+\frac12\right)$